# How to disable autofill for input drop-down list in angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

```
<div class="row" style="display:inline-flex;margin-left:11% !important">

              <label>Employee</label>

              <input id="txtIncurredBy" type="search" list="employeesList"  (change)="GetSelectedEmployeeDetails($event)" formControlName="incurredBy"  />

              <datalist id="employeesList">

                <option *ngFor="let employee of employeesList" [ngValue]="employee.name">{{employee.name}}</option>

              </datalist>

              <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="FindEmployee()">Find</button>

            </div>

 

employeesList=[{

    "seqID": "1433174",

    "name": "Revankar,Anuj A",

    "property": null,

    "firstName": "Anuj ARevankar"

}]
```

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bEPX.png)

When I type "anuj re" in the drop-down , the list has an option in it as seen in the employeeslist, but as you can see in the screen shot, the option is not available;I realise that the value typed doesn't match with the list value, but is there any way I can show all values in the list regardless it matches or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
<kendo-combobox
      [data]="employeesList"
      [filterable]="true"
      [textField]="'name'"
      [valueField]="'name'"
      (valueChange)="GetSelectedEmployeeDetails($event)">
    </kendo-combobox>
```

Using a kendo combo-box will work for the given requirement.
Here is the link: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/combobox/

Feels weird to answer own question